# How to call Fetch post API to ASP.NET generic handler in react?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, post, webforms, fetch-api

I am using ReactJS with ASP.NET Web Forms,  in onChange of an autocomplete component a genric handler is called to update datasource.

So Used fetch API post call in onChange of the Autocomplete component , weird thing is sometime I do get a response and sometimes the fetch API is blocked as seen in chrome developer tool.Have applied all CORS headers on the server side too, but fail to understand why it fails only sometimes.

Error

index.js:39 POST http://localhost:53107/INV/MKRF/Handlers/Handler.ashx net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Index.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        itemcodes: [],
        selected: null,
        qty: '',
        rows: []
    };


}


handlechange = (e) => {
    //console.log(e);
    this.setState({
        selected: e.value
    });

    var data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append("method", "GetAllBAANItemCodes");
    data.append("prefix", this.state.selected);
    fetch('Handlers/Handler.ashx', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",              
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*"
            //'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: data
    }).then((response) => { response.json(); })
        .then((data) => { this.setState({ itemcodes: data }); })
        .catch(
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );

}



render() {
    return (
                    <Autocomplete
                        dataSource={this.state.itemcodes}
                        value={this.state.selected}
                        onValueChanged={(e) => this.handlechange(e)}
                        placeholder={'Type first name...'}
                    />


    );
}
```

}

hanlder code

```
Public Class Handler : Implements IHttpHandler

Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim method As String = context.Request("method")
    If method = "GetAllBAANItemCodes" Then
        Dim prefix As String = context.Request("prefix")
        Dim conBAAN As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        conBAAN.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BAAN").ConnectionString
        conBAAN.Open()
        Dim itemCodes As New List(Of String)
        Dim cmdBAAN As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmdBAAN.Connection = conBAAN
        cmdBAAN.Connection = conBAAN
        cmdBAAN.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdBAAN.CommandText = <some query>
        cmdBAAN.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix)
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmdBAAN.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            While rdr.Read
                itemCodes.Add(rdr("t_item").ToString())
            End While
        End If

        rdr.Close()
        cmdBAAN.Dispose()
        conBAAN.Close()

        Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemCodes))
```

Comment: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT almost always means you have some ad-blocking extension or privacy extension which is blocking the request. So, try turning off your extensions, or try it in another browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes as suggested by @sideshowbarker ,the browser had a ForcePoint extension installed by the company which gave the error.